# How to make HA Proxy keepalive

Tags: haproxy, keep-alive

In my environment I have haproxy load balance for 2 web servers (Apache), this is my HA Proxy configuration :

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
        tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    daemon
        nbproc      1
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
        stats       timeout 1m
        nogetaddrinfo
listen front
    bind :80
    redirect scheme https if { hdr(Host) -i domain.com } !{ ssl_fc }
listen front_ssl
    bind :443 ssl crt /opt/certificate/domain.pem
    mode http
        option dontlognull
    stats      enable
    stats      uri /ha?stats
    stats      realm system
    stats      auth root:*********
    stats      refresh 5s
    option http-keep-alive
    option forwardfor
    option redispatch
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
         timeout client  15s
        timeout connect 3s
        timeout server  15s
        timeout http-request 15s
        timeout http-keep-alive 15s
        default_backend bk_http
backend bk_http
        mode http
        balance source
        option http-keep-alive
        default-server inter 1s
        retries 3
        timeout connect 3s
        timeout server  15s
        timeout queue 60s
        timeout check 10s
        timeout http-request 15s
        timeout http-keep-alive 15s
        server node1 1.2.3.4:82 check id 1 weight 1 maxconn 2000 maxqueue 2000
        server node2 5.6.7.8:82 check id 1 weight 1 maxconn 2000 maxqueue 2000
```

"KeepAlive On" in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
But when I test with curl, I see that keepalive is not work :

```
curl -Iv http://domain.com 2>&1 | grep -i 'connection #0'
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Closing connection #0
curl -Iv https://domain.com 2>&1 | grep -i 'connection #0'
* Closing connection #0
```

As I know if keepalive is working, result should be :

```
  0   162    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0* Connection #0 to host domain.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Please let me know if something wrong in my configuration ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 12):

You have the right configuration. You simply require `option http-keep-alive` which is the default as of haproxy 1.5. Do check which version you have installed.

See http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt section 4. *Proxies*

> In HTTP mode, the processing applied to requests and responses flowing over
>   a connection depends in the combination of the frontend's HTTP options and
>   the backend's. HAProxy supports 5 connection modes :
>
> - KAL : keep alive ("option http-keep-alive") which is the default mode : all
>     requests and responses are processed, and connections remain open but idle
>     between responses and new requests.
> - TUN: tunnel ("option http-tunnel") : this was the default mode for versions
>     1.0 to 1.5-dev21 : only the first request and response are processed, and
>     everything else is forwarded with no analysis at all. This mode should not
>     be used as it creates lots of trouble with logging and HTTP processing.
> - PCL: passive close ("option httpclose") : exactly the same as tunnel mode,
>     but with "Connection: close" appended in both directions to try to make
>     both ends close after the first request/response exchange.
> - SCL: server close ("option http-server-close") : the server-facing
>     connection is closed after the end of the response is received, but the
>     client-facing connection remains open.
> - FCL: forced close ("option forceclose") : the connection is actively closed
>     after the end of the response.

Your backends, node1/node2, are probably closing the connection. They may not have keepalives enabled.

If you intercept the traffic check for http/1.1 and no "Connection: close" header