# GCP External HTTP(S) Load Balancer Returns 502: "backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, haproxy

My HTTP(S) External Load Balancer on GCP occasionally returns response with error code 502.

And the reason for the response is as follows:

```
jsonPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry"
statusDetails: "backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client"
}
```

According to GCP documentation such response occurs because of the following reason:

> The backend unexpectedly closed its connection to the load balancer
> before the response was proxied to the client. This can happen if the
> load balancer is sending traffic to another entity. The other entity
> might be a third-party load balancer that has a TCP timeout that is
> shorter than the external HTTP(S) load balancer's 10-minute
> (600-second) timeout. The third-party load balancer might be running
> on a VM instance. Manually setting the TCP timeout (keepalive) on the
> target service to greater than 600 seconds might resolve the issue.

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring).

In the backend of my load balancer I have a GCP VM that runs an HAProxy server (v1.8) with following configuration:

```
global
    log         /dev/log    local0
    log         /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/rh-haproxy18-haproxy.pid

    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    stats       socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners

    spread-checks  21

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base     /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base    /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
    #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option                  http-server-close
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3

    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 10000
    balance                 roundrobin


frontend http-80
        bind *:80
        mode http
        option httplog
        default_backend www-80

backend www-80
        balance roundrobin
        mode http
        option httpchk /haproxy_status
        http-check expect status 200
        rspidel ^Server:.*
        rspidel ^server:.*
        rspidel ^x-envoy-upstream-service-time:.*
        server backendnode1 node-1:80 check port 8080 fall 3 rise 2 inter 1597
        server backendnode2 node-2:80 check port 8080 fall 3 rise 2 inter 1597
        

frontend health-80
    bind *:8080
    acl backend_dead nbsrv(www-80) lt 1
    monitor-uri /haproxy_status
    monitor fail if backend_dead

listen stats # Define a listen section called "stats"
    bind :9000 # Listen on localhost:9000
    mode http
    stats enable  # Enable stats page
    stats hide-version  # Hide HAProxy version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics  # Title text for popup window
    stats uri /haproxy_stats  # Stats URI
    stats auth haproxy:pass  # Authentication credentials
    
#lastline
```

According to GCP documentation we can get rid of 502 errors by setting a TCP Keep-Alive value that is higher than 600 seconds (10 minutes).

They have suggested values for Apache and Nginx.

```
Web server software  Parameter          Default setting         Recommended setting
Apache               KeepAliveTimeout   KeepAliveTimeout 5      KeepAliveTimeout 620
nginx                keepalive_timeout  keepalive_timeout 75s;  keepalive_timeout 620s;
```

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#timeouts_and_retries).

I'm not sure what timeout values or what config should I change in my HAProxy configuration to set keepalive time more than 600s.

Is setting the `timeout http-keep-alive` more than 600 seconds do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You version of HAProxy should have `keep-alive` option enabled by default but I don't see the corresponding line in your config file;

to enable it you need to add the `option http-keep-alive` line in the `defaults` section so it will look like this:

```
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option                  http-server-close
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    option                  http-keep-alive
```

To check if it's working follow instructions from [this anwer](https://serverfault.com/questions/199434/how-do-i-make-curl-use-keepalive-from-the-command-line).

You may also find useful these threads on SO:

[How to make HA Proxy keepalive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162452/how-to-make-ha-proxy-keepalive)

[How to enable keep-alive in haproxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966813/how-to-enable-keep-alive-in-haproxy)

Comment: @Wojtek_B the setting ```option http-keep-alive``` in ```default``` section doesn't seem to work. I suspect it could be because I already have ```option http-server-close``` setup there. I need to verify it further.

Comment: Have you tried to use `option http-keep-alive` instead of `option http-server-close`?

Comment: Just ran into a different, but mildly similar issue. (mostly posting this for future googlers) Same error, but different scenario ArgoCD protected by IAP/HTTPS via GKE Ingress Controller. ArgoCD had built in HTTPS self-signed cert, what resolved the error was adding the following annotation to the ArgoCD kube service. 
cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"web":"HTTPS"}'